# Prove $[z^{1/2}]$ has no holomorphic branch on any open ball $B(0,R)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, branch-points

> Prove the multifunction $[z^{1/2}]$ has no holomorphic branch on $B(0,r)$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $f: B(0,r) /(-\infty,0] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic branch of $[z^{1/2}]$. Note $-f$ defines another holomorphic branch on the same cutplane.

For sake of contradiction assume $h: B(0,r) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic branch of $[z^{1/2}]$.
We want $h(z) \in [z^{1/2}]$, which requires $|z|^{1/2} = |h(z)|$ and $\arg(h(z))  \in [\arg(z^{1/2})]$, so  $\arg(h(z)) = \frac{\theta}{2} + 2\pi n(z)$, where $\theta \in [\arg(z)]$ is the principal argument and $n: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is some integer valued function. Therefore $h(z)=|z^{1/2}|e^{\frac{i( \theta + 2 \pi n(z))}{2}}$.

Consider $g(z) :=\frac{h(z)}{f(z)}$, where we assume $f(z) \neq 0$. Then, $g(z)=e^{i\pi n(z)} \in \{-1,1\}$.  Since $g$ is continuous on a connected domain $g$, is constant, so that $h= \pm f $, which is impossible because $ \pm f$ cannot be holomorphically extended to $B(0,r)$*. That completes my argument, as we have hopefully arrived at a contradiction.

*[$ \lim_{z \to -1} h(z)= \pm f(z)$ approaching above the cut $\neq \lim_{z \to -1} h(z)= \pm f(z)$ approaching below the cut.]

If correct, does this method generalize?

Is my working correct? Thanks!

Comment: Continue analytically along a circle to find that $f(e^{2i\pi} z)\ne f(z) \implies f$ isn't analytic on $0<|z|<r$. Note that $z^{1/2},|z-1|< 1$ is "locally analytic on $\Bbb{C}^*$" its analytic continuation exists along every curve in $\Bbb{C}^*$ starting at $1$.

Comment: Thanks! I so far haven't looked at analytic continuation, so could you perhaps verify my approach?

Comment: My idea was to mimic the answer provided here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662779/show-holomorphic-branch-of-log-z-on-omega-mathbbc-backslash-z-text-re?rq=1

Comment: See also my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3358049 .